# kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange frame to UIImage conversion

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, avfoundation

I have an app that capture live video in kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange format to process Y channel. According to Apple's documentation:

> kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange
>   Bi-Planar Component Y'CbCr 8-bit 4:2:0, full-range (luma=[0,255] chroma=[1,255]). baseAddr points to a big-endian CVPlanarPixelBufferInfo_YCbCrBiPlanar struct.

I want to present some of these frames in a UIViewController, is there any API to make the conversion to kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA format? Can you give some hint to tune this method provided by Apple?

```
// Create a UIImage from sample buffer data
- (UIImage *) imageFromSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef) sampleBuffer  {
    // Get a CMSampleBuffer's Core Video image buffer for the media data
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    // Lock the base address of the pixel buffer
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);

    // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
    void *baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);

    // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
    // Get the pixel buffer width and height
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);

    // Create a device-dependent RGB color space
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    // Create a bitmap graphics context with the sample buffer data
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8,
                                                 bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    // Create a Quartz image from the pixel data in the bitmap graphics context
    CGImageRef quartzImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    // Unlock the pixel buffer
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

    // Free up the context and color space
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    // Create an image object from the Quartz image
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:quartzImage];

    // Release the Quartz image
    CGImageRelease(quartzImage);

    return (image);
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 16):

Most implementations I found (including the previous answer here) won't work if you change `videoOrientation` in the `AVCaptureConnection` (for some reason I don't fully understand, the `CVPlanarPixelBufferInfo_YCbCrBiPlanar` struct will be empty in that case), so I wrote one that does (most of the code was based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30497777/16)). My implementation also adds an empty alpha channel to the RGB buffer and creates the `CGBitmapContext` using the `kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast` flag (there's no alpha data, but iOS seems to require 4 bytes per pixel). Here it is:

```m
#define clamp(a) (a>255?255:(a<0?0:a))

- (UIImage *)imageFromSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer {
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);
    uint8_t *yBuffer = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0);
    size_t yPitch = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0);
    uint8_t *cbCrBuffer = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer, 1);
    size_t cbCrPitch = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(imageBuffer, 1);

    int bytesPerPixel = 4;
    uint8_t *rgbBuffer = malloc(width * height * bytesPerPixel);

    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        uint8_t *rgbBufferLine = &rgbBuffer[y * width * bytesPerPixel];
        uint8_t *yBufferLine = &yBuffer[y * yPitch];
        uint8_t *cbCrBufferLine = &cbCrBuffer[(y >> 1) * cbCrPitch];

        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            int16_t y = yBufferLine[x];
            int16_t cb = cbCrBufferLine[x & ~1] - 128;
            int16_t cr = cbCrBufferLine[x | 1] - 128;

            uint8_t *rgbOutput = &rgbBufferLine[x*bytesPerPixel];

            int16_t r = (int16_t)roundf( y + cr *  1.4 );
            int16_t g = (int16_t)roundf( y + cb * -0.343 + cr * -0.711 );
            int16_t b = (int16_t)roundf( y + cb *  1.765);

            rgbOutput[0] = 0xff;
            rgbOutput[1] = clamp(b);
            rgbOutput[2] = clamp(g);
            rgbOutput[3] = clamp(r);
        }
    }

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rgbBuffer, width, height, 8, width * bytesPerPixel, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast);
    CGImageRef quartzImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:quartzImage];

    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGImageRelease(quartzImage);
    free(rgbBuffer);

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);

    return image;
}
```

Comment: This works great, I can easily get UIImage from the frames, but I am facing an issue while retrieving bitmap pixel data from the CGImageRef with below code. but UIImage obtained from your code looks good, its only problem after getting bitmap data

`CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(quartzImage));`

My original image is white color, the result images from the code is in purple.. can you get the issue?

Answer (score 15):

I'm not aware of any accessible built-in way to convert a biplanar Y / CbCr image to RGB in iOS. However you should be able to perform the conversion yourself in software, e.g.

```
uint8_t clamp(int16_t input)
{
    // clamp negative numbers to 0; assumes signed shifts
    // (a valid assumption on iOS)
    input &= ~(num >> 16);

    // clamp numbers greater than 255 to 255; the accumulation
    // of the mask looks odd but is an attempt to avoid
    // pipeline stalls
    uint8_t saturationMask = num >> 8;
    saturationMask |= saturationMask << 4;
    saturationMask |= saturationMask << 2;
    saturationMask |= saturationMask << 1;
    num |= saturationMask;

    return num&0xff;
}

...

CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);

size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);

uint8_t *baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);
CVPlanarPixelBufferInfo_YCbCrBiPlanar *bufferInfo = (CVPlanarPixelBufferInfo_YCbCrBiPlanar *)baseAddress;

NSUInteger yOffset = EndianU32_BtoN(bufferInfo->componentInfoY.offset);
NSUInteger yPitch = EndianU32_BtoN(bufferInfo->componentInfoY.rowBytes);

NSUInteger cbCrOffset = EndianU32_BtoN(bufferInfo->componentInfoCbCr.offset);
NSUInteger cbCrPitch = EndianU32_BtoN(bufferInfo->componentInfoCbCr.rowBytes);

uint8_t *rgbBuffer = malloc(width * height * 3);
uint8_t *yBuffer = baseAddress + yOffset;
uint8_t *cbCrBuffer = baseAddress + cbCrOffset;

for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    uint8_t *rgbBufferLine = &rgbBuffer[y * width * 3];
    uint8_t *yBufferLine = &yBuffer[y * yPitch];
    uint8_t *cbCrBufferLine = &cbCrBuffer[(y >> 1) * cbCrPitch];

    for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        // from ITU-R BT.601, rounded to integers
        uint8_t y = yBufferLine[x] - 16;
        uint8_t cb = cbCrBufferLine[x & ~1] - 128;
        uint8_t cr = cbCrBufferLine[x | 1] - 128;

        uint8_t *rgbOutput = &rgbBufferLine[x*3];

        rgbOutput[0] = clamp(((298 * y + 409 * cr - 223) >> 8) - 223);
        rgbOutput[1] = clamp(((298 * y - 100 * cb - 208 * cr + 136) >> 8) + 136);
        rgbOutput[2] = clamp(((298 * y + 516 * cb - 277) >> 8) - 277);
    }

}
```

Just written directly into this box and untested, I think I've got the cb/cr extraction correct. You'd then use `CGBitmapContextCreate` with `rgbBuffer` to create a `CGImage` and hence a `UIImage`.

Comment: The conversion to RGB is just an intermediate step, yes. The problem with your solution is that this API is not available in iOS 5.0. There is a method called imageWithCVPixelBuffer that I could use instead, but as my original format is biplanar, I have two pixel buffers. :-( Thanks anyway!

Comment: Sorry; I stupidly loaded the wrong page in Safari and was sitting there looking at the OS X documentation for CIImage rather than the iOS. I'll write a new answer.

Comment: Tommy, thank you for your code. It works like a champ with a few changes. I would like to vote up for you but I dont have enough reputation.

Comment: This isn't working for me and crashes on " uint8_t y = yBufferLine[x];". Julian, what "few changes" did you make? Can you please post final solution?

Comment: @MichaelG have you tried adding a `CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType` check for `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange`? Are you otherwise getting sensible numbers for `yPitch`, etc?

Comment: why not write a yuv->rgb GLES2 shader?

Comment: There are two things wrong with the code that I've found so far.  First, the math is wrong for green.  You subtract, not add, the red and blue components.  Second, blacks end up wrapping around to high values.  So you need to replace each of the math bits with a function that assigns the value to a larger, *signed* integer, then check to see if the result is <= 0, and if it is, clamp the result to 0.  Otherwise, return the result.

Comment: Correction: You need to clamp both ends of the range.

Comment: @dgatwood - FYI, Just seen your comment! I have been having trouble with this formula too, So I asked a question here. http://stackoverflow.com/q/25210852/296446 Im going to try and make an answer based on your suggestions.

Comment: It looks like I made quite a few errors in the original post. Hopefully they're corrected now.

Comment: No worries you typed it straight into the box! :) - FYI - I got it working using this code now.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/25211688/296446

Comment: Are you able to call CGBitmapContextCreate with a 3-component buffer? I think iOS only supports 4-color (RGBA/ARGB) pixel formats, though you can tell it to ignore the alpha. I had to enlarge the buffer to be 4 bytesPerPixel to make this work. Otherwise, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

These other answers with the bit shifting and the magic variables are wild. Here's an alternative approach using the Accelerate framework in Swift 5. It takes a frame from a buffer with pixel format `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange` (Bi-Planar Component Y'CbCr 8-bit 4:2:0) and makes a `UIImage` from it after converting it to `ARGB8888`. But you could probably modify it to handle any input/output formats:

```swift
import Accelerate
import CoreGraphics
import CoreMedia
import Foundation
import QuartzCore
import UIKit

func createImage(from sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) -> UIImage? {
    guard let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else {
      return nil
    }

    // pixel format is Bi-Planar Component Y'CbCr 8-bit 4:2:0, full-range (luma=[0,255] chroma=[1,255]).
    // baseAddr points to a big-endian CVPlanarPixelBufferInfo_YCbCrBiPlanar struct.
    //
    guard CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType(imageBuffer) == kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange else {
        return nil
    }


    guard CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, .readOnly) == kCVReturnSuccess else {
        return nil
    }

    defer {
        // be sure to unlock the base address before returning
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, .readOnly)
    }

    // 1st plane is luminance, 2nd plane is chrominance
    guard CVPixelBufferGetPlaneCount(imageBuffer) == 2 else {
        return nil
    }

    // 1st plane
    guard let lumaBaseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0) else {
        return nil
    }

    let lumaWidth = CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0)
    let lumaHeight = CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0)
    let lumaBytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0)
    var lumaBuffer = vImage_Buffer(
        data: lumaBaseAddress,
        height: vImagePixelCount(lumaHeight),
        width: vImagePixelCount(lumaWidth),
        rowBytes: lumaBytesPerRow
    )

    // 2nd plane
    guard let chromaBaseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer, 1) else {
        return nil
    }

    let chromaWidth = CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(imageBuffer, 1)
    let chromaHeight = CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(imageBuffer, 1)
    let chromaBytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(imageBuffer, 1)
    var chromaBuffer = vImage_Buffer(
        data: chromaBaseAddress,
        height: vImagePixelCount(chromaHeight),
        width: vImagePixelCount(chromaWidth),
        rowBytes: chromaBytesPerRow
    )

    var argbBuffer = vImage_Buffer()

    defer {
        // we are responsible for freeing the buffer data
        free(argbBuffer.data)
    }

    // initialize the empty buffer
    guard vImageBuffer_Init(
        &argbBuffer,
        lumaBuffer.height,
        lumaBuffer.width,
        32,
        vImage_Flags(kvImageNoFlags)
        ) == kvImageNoError else {
            return nil
    }

    // full range 8-bit, clamped to full range, is necessary for correct color reproduction
    var pixelRange = vImage_YpCbCrPixelRange(
        Yp_bias: 0,
        CbCr_bias: 128,
        YpRangeMax: 255,
        CbCrRangeMax: 255,
        YpMax: 255,
        YpMin: 1,
        CbCrMax: 255,
        CbCrMin: 0
    )

    var conversionInfo = vImage_YpCbCrToARGB()

    // initialize the conversion info
    guard vImageConvert_YpCbCrToARGB_GenerateConversion(
        kvImage_YpCbCrToARGBMatrix_ITU_R_601_4, // Y'CbCr-to-RGB conversion matrix for ITU Recommendation BT.601-4.
        &pixelRange,
        &conversionInfo,
        kvImage420Yp8_CbCr8, // converting from
        kvImageARGB8888, // converting to
        vImage_Flags(kvImageNoFlags)
        ) == kvImageNoError else {
            return nil
    }

    // do the conversion
    guard vImageConvert_420Yp8_CbCr8ToARGB8888(
        &lumaBuffer, // in
        &chromaBuffer, // in
        &argbBuffer, // out
        &conversionInfo,
        nil,
        255,
        vImage_Flags(kvImageNoFlags)
        ) == kvImageNoError else {
            return nil
    }

    // core foundation objects are automatically memory mananged. no need to call CGContextRelease() or CGColorSpaceRelease()
    guard let context = CGContext(
        data: argbBuffer.data,
        width: Int(argbBuffer.width),
        height: Int(argbBuffer.height),
        bitsPerComponent: 8,
        bytesPerRow: argbBuffer.rowBytes,
        space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
        bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue
        ) else {
            return nil
    }

    guard let cgImage = context.makeImage() else {
        return nil
    }

    return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage) 
}
```

Comment: Best solution Ive found for swift. Note that you can additionally add `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange` to that format type check and it will still work as expected.

Comment: Thanks! with some tweaks you've helped me make a realtime convertion