# Create UIImage from CMSampleBufferRef using video format kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage, video-processing, pixelformat

Im capturing from the iphone camera device using CVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange for faster processing of the grayscale plane (plane 0).
I am storing an amount of frames in memory for later video creation. Before I was creating the video in grayscale so I was storing only the plane that contains the luminiscense (plane 0).

Now I have to store both planes and also create a color video from them, for storing the frames I use something like this  :

```
bytesInFrame = width * height * 2; //2 bytes per pixel, is that correct?
frameData = (unsigned char*) malloc(bytesInFrame  * numbeOfFrames);
```

The function for creating the image from the grayscale buffer I was using :

```
- (UIImage *) convertBitmapGrayScaleToUIImage:(unsigned char *) buffer 
                                withWidth:(int) width
                               withHeight:(int) height {


size_t bufferLength = width * height * 1;
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer, bufferLength, NULL);
size_t bitsPerComponent = 8;
size_t bitsPerPixel = 8;
size_t bytesPerRow = 1 * width;

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
if(colorSpaceRef == NULL) {
    DLog(@"Error allocating color space");
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    return nil;
}

CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;

CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;

CGImageRef iref = CGImageCreate(width, 
                                height, 
                                bitsPerComponent, 
                                bitsPerPixel, 
                                bytesPerRow, 
                                colorSpaceRef, 
                                bitmapInfo, 
                                provider,   // data provider
                                NULL,       // decode
                                YES,            // should interpolate
                                renderingIntent);

uint32_t* pixels = (uint32_t*)malloc(bufferLength);

if(pixels == NULL) {
    DLog(@"Error: Memory not allocated for bitmap");
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
    CGImageRelease(iref);       
    return nil;
}

CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels, 
                                             width, 
                                             height, 
                                             bitsPerComponent, 
                                             bytesPerRow, 
                                             colorSpaceRef, 
                                             bitmapInfo); 

if(context == NULL) {
    DLog(@"Error context not created");
    free(pixels);
}

UIImage *image = nil;
if(context) {

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, width, height), iref);

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

    image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

    CGImageRelease(imageRef);   
    CGContextRelease(context);  
}

CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
CGImageRelease(iref);
CGDataProviderRelease(provider);

if(pixels) {
    free(pixels);
}   
return image;
}
```

I have seen that this question is similar to what I want to achieve :
[kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange frame to UIImage conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838481/kcvpixelformattype-420ypcbcr8biplanarfullrange-frame-to-uiimage-conversion)
But I think this would add an extra step to my conversion.

There is any way of creating a color UIImage form the buffer directly? 
I would appreciate some indications.

Comment: If you eventually need a UIImage instance, you better capture frames in the RGB format (kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA) to start with. Then the conversion will be done by Apple's code (which is hopefully highly optimized), and your code will be simpler. BTW: "I am storing an amount of frames in memory..." sounds like asking for memory problems.

Comment: I need to process the grayscale image, thats why Im using biplanar video format. Before to this approach I was capturing frames in RGB format and doing conversion to grayscale on the fly and the performance was really slow (8 to 12 fps). Using biplanar video format allows me to get directly the grayscale image and process it, its increases the frame rate up to 28 fps. Thats the reason for using biplanar. About the "memory problems" you comment I don't see why, Im having a circular buffer well defined.

Comment: If speed of conversion to grayscale is a problem, may I suggest my GPUImageGrayscaleFilter: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage ? It can process 640x480 RGB frames to grayscale in under 2 ms on an iPhone 4. In fact, the whole video recording and photo capturing pipeline there might be able to replace what you're writing here. I may try migrating my capture from BGRA to YUV at some point, but the BGRA uploads are not the bottleneck in my realtime video processing.

Comment: Brad, I have checked early today your GPUImage framework, thanks for releasing such a good work. Tomorrow I will give it a try (today I just tested your examples and seems extremely fast) . A couple of questions? Is the grayscale output real grayscale? (1byte per pixel?) Can I pipe the non-processed data to a circular buffer? Thanks again.

Comment: You probably have already found this out, but the grayscale conversion reduces the image to its luminance component (1 byte) and writes that same value across the red, green, and blue color values. You only need to sample from one of those colors if you want to do later processing (see my Sobel edge detection filter, where I do this). I don't yet have a ring buffer type storage system for later access of video frames, but it's something I'm working on. I should have that ready soon, because I want it for some other processing tasks.