# Why is the Y-plane and the CbCr-plane reporting different sizes?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, video-capture, video-processing

```
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);

const size_t lumaPlaneIndex = 0;
size_t lumaPlaneWidth = CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(pixelBuffer, lumaPlaneIndex);
size_t lumaPlaneHeight = CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(pixelBuffer, lumaPlaneIndex);

const size_t cbcrPlaneIndex = 1;
size_t cbcrPlaneWidth = CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(pixelBuffer, cbcrPlaneIndex);
size_t cbcrPlaneHeight = CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(pixelBuffer, cbcrPlaneIndex);

NSLog(@"lumaPlaneWidth: %zu", lumaPlaneWidth);
NSLog(@"lumaPlaneHeight: %zu", lumaPlaneHeight);
NSLog(@"cbcrPlaneWidth: %zu", cbcrPlaneWidth);
NSLog(@"cbcrPlaneHeight: %zu", cbcrPlaneHeight);

CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
```

Output on my iPhone 5 running iOS 7 for the front facing camera is:

```
lumaPlaneWidth: 1280
lumaPlaneHeight: 720
cbcrPlaneWidth: 640
cbcrPlaneHeight: 360
```

The luma (Y) plane is twice the size of the CbCr plane, why is this?

Comment: 1280x720 is 720p. Why are you expecting it to be half that size? Are you asking about Cb and Cr being sampled at a lower frequency?

Comment: @Tommy - Actually you might be right, I was confused as to why the planes had different dimensions, I might have incorrectly assumed that the luma plane was wrong.  Ill re-word the questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The human eye is much more sensitive to changes in brightness than to changes in colour. It can discern them at a higher frequency, so that information is usually stored at a higher sampling frequency. The motivation is simply the reality of human perception (plus, I guess, some consideration of bandwidth: you'd just capture as much as physically possible if data transmission were free).

The buffer you're getting has the Y (/brightness) channel sampled at four times the sampling rate of the Cb and Cr (/colour) channels. That's 4:1:1 [chroma subsampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling).

Furthermore, 99.9999% of digital cameras capture using a colour filter (almost always a [Bayer filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayer_filter) specifically) which means they don't actually capture the full colour at every site but rather capture individual primary components at adjoining sites and then combine them mathematically. That problem gets non-trivial if you want a really good estimate of the true signal. If you're expecting someone only to need 4:1:1 then it's cheaper to [demosaic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demosaic) directly to 4:1:1. That's why the API isn't giving you 4:4:4, regardless of it not knowing what you intend to do with the data.

Comment: Ah cool - thanks for your answer.  I understood that there is more information in the luma plane, since the CR,CB planes are interleaved, something like: `YYYYYYYYYYYYBRBRBRBRBRBR` however, if the CrCB plan is 1/2 the size in each dimension then is 1/4th the overall area, and if only half of the plane is Cr and half Cb then isn't it `8:1:1`?  ...Maybe Im missing something?

Comment: Also I have just seen your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8838723/296446, If I understand it correctly, this accounts for the size in plane sizes by bit shifting the index like so: `uint8_t *cbCrBufferLine = &cbCrBuffer[(y >> 1) * cbCrPitch];`