# How can I fix this YCrCb -> RBG conversion formula?

Tags: ios, c, image, image-processing, colors

Im using a formula from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838481/kcvpixelformattype-420ypcbcr8biplanarfullrange-frame-to-uiimage-conversion):

```
uint8_t *rgbBuffer = malloc(imageWidth * imageHeight * 3);

// .. iterate over height and width

// from ITU-R BT.601, rounded to integers
rgbOutput[0] = (298 * (y - 16) + 409 * cr - 223) >> 8;
rgbOutput[1] = (298 * (y - 16) + 100 * cb + 208 * cr + 136) >> 8;
rgbOutput[2] = (298 * (y - 16) + 516 * cb - 277) >> 8;
```

Which I assume is based in the [ITU-R_BT.601 formula in the wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr#ITU-R_BT.601_conversion).

[image]

However I think the formula is not quite right because the output image looks like this:

[image: I don't actually have green hair]

How do I fix the formula?

Comment: Could it be integer overflow/underflow issues?

Comment: What type is your array?

Comment: @FiddlingBits - Byte array `uint8_t *rgbBuffer = malloc(imageWidth * imageHeight * 3);` Ill add to the question.

Comment: +1 great presentation of the question, quoting the code from the other question, and especially the image showing what's wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming max values for the first calculation (`y == 255` and `cr == 255`):

```
rgbOutput[0] = (298 * (255 - 16) + 409 * 255 - 223) >> 8;
rgbOutput[0] = (298 * 239 + 104295 - 223) >> 8;
rgbOutput[0] = (71222 + 104295 - 223) >> 8;
rgbOutput[0] = 175294 >> 8; // 175294 == 0x2ACBE
rgbOutput[0] = 684; // 684 == 0x2AC
```

The maximum value that `rgbOutput[0]` can hold is `255`.  You're attempting to assign `684` to it, resulting in truncation.  The actual value assigned to it is `172` (`0xAC`).

**EDIT 1**

According to the formula you posted, your first calculation should be as follows:

```
rgbOutput[0] = ((298 * y) >> 8) + ((409 * cr) >> 8) - 223;
```

This results in a value of (assuming max values for `y` and `cr`) of `480`, which results in truncation as well.

**EDIT 2**

The following equation is said to be recommended:

[image: equation]

Using this instead, your first calculation should be like this:

```
rgbOutput[0] = ((255 * (y - 16)) / 219) + ((179 * (cr - 128)) / 112;
```

This results in a value of (assuming max values for `y` and `cr`) of `480` (the same answer in EDIT 1), which results in truncation as well.

**EDIT 3**

See answer from @Robert for complete solution.

**EDIT 4**

When `y == 0` and `cr == 0`, the value that is written to `y` will also result in truncation unless clamping is performed.

Comment: Yes - you are right. I added the formula that its based on into the question.  It also appears there are also some missing constants.

Comment: Great - the image looks much better now! There a just a few strange areas that I think are a result of truncation.  Do you know what the most efficient way to truncate a value is? Do I just store it in an `int` and then check its size with an if statement?

Comment: Actually no worries, I found this http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/6502/30438.  Ill give the clamping a try myself!

Comment: @Robert You don't want truncation, because the RGB values should fall between 0 and 255, right?

Comment: Yes - I meant clamping not truncation.  I just modified the formula and it now works beautifully.  Thank you for your help! :)  Ill submit my modifications for completeness.

Comment: Okay, that sounds good. Clamp values above 255 to 255. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

With help from @Fiddling Bits.  The corrected code is like so:

```
uint8_t ClampIntToByte(int n) {
    n = n > 255 ? 255 : n;
    return n < 0 ? 0 : n;
}

rgbOutput[0] = ClampIntToByte(((298 * (y - 16) + 409 * cr) >> 8) - 223);
rgbOutput[1] = ClampIntToByte(((298 * (y - 16) - 100 * cb - 208 * cr) >> 8) + 136);
rgbOutput[2] = ClampIntToByte(((298 * (y - 16) + 516 * cb) >> 8) - 277);
```

Comment: Missed the clamping part in the previous question's answer. Good catch.